# Login to Spotify fails when using ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, spotify, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm using the Spotify SDK in an iOS app and login is working when running in the simulator or running on a device when I've installed the app directly from Xcode. When I distribute an Ad-Hoc build of the app (using Fabric) the method call

```
[self.player loginWithAccessToken:self.auth.session.accessToken];
```

fails to complete and the user is never logged in. If following  [Spotify's own tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/) this method gets called on the main thread and so blocks it, if I wrap it in a dispatch_async call onto a background thread then the UI is not blocked but the user is still not logged in.

I have tried with both a wildcard provisioning profile and an app specific one but that didn't make a difference.

The demo project included with [the iOS-beta 25 SDK](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk) does work (can login) when distributing an Ad-Hoc build. That is using Spotify's example app, callback and client ID and similar but not identical code.

My question is then what I am not doing for a distributed build that I should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that has the same problem I have found a solution. It seems the problem was due to not using refresh tokens or at least adding refresh tokens got things working.

I managed to get my app working by following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE) and referring to the code in the demo project found with [the Spotify SDK](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk) . The ruby app used in the tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/simontaen/SpotifyTokenSwap).

I hope that helps someone else too, I didn't make detailed notes about what I did so can't give anymore info than that but happy to try and help if you have a question.